# Invalid single-table inheritance type: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this error when trying to create a new Product in my Rails application.

> Invalid single-table inheritance type: Movie is not a subclass of
>   Product

How can I resolve this?

[image]

controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :artist, :type, :release_date, :category, :publisher, :format, :description, :sale_price, :rental_price)
    end
end
```

migration

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :artist
      t.string :type
      t.date :release_date
      t.string :category
      t.string :publisher
      t.string :format
      t.text :description
      t.decimal :sale_price
      t.decimal :rental_price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: make sure you have Movie class that extends Product

Comment: extending @Muntasim comment: check that you have in your models: `class Product < ActiveRecord::Base` and `class Movie < Product`

Comment: So I have go create a new Model + Controller anytime I want a new Product type? @MrYoshiji

Comment: If your `Movie` class does not have anything special to do except categorization then you need not use STI. Otherwise you have to have all possible classes defined and you `Type` field should be select box instead of free text.

Comment: Nope, you can just use the ProductsController and use a params[:type] to handle a certain kind of Product -- for the model, yes you'll have to create a new model for each new type of Product. Do you want me to post an answer with some examples @AntarrByrd ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Please do.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**You should not use the `type` keyword** as the column name because **it is a reserved word for ActiveRecord**.

---

But if you really want to use it, for any reason (like if you don't have control on the DB structure), here is what you should do:

First, make sure your Movie model inherits from the (false-)"abstract" model Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = %w( Movie )
  before_save :set_type
  validates :type, presence: true, :inclusion => { :in => TYPES }

  def set_type
    raiser "You must override this method in each model inheriting from Product!"
  end

  # ...

class Movie < Product

  def set_type # If you don't implement this method, an error will be raised
    self.type = 'Movie'
  end
```

And then in your ProductsController you can manage (CRUD) all kind of products.

---

**To add a new type of product:** you just have to define a new Model inheriting from Product, implement it's set_type method and add the type in the product's Constant:

```
class Book < Product
  def set_type
    self.type = 'Book'
  end
  #...

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = %w( Movie Book )
```

Comment: When using this method it seems I still have create a Movies controller that inherits from from the products controller

Comment: If you are using the `rails generate model` command it might create a Controller for you, but you can delete it (and the corresponding routes) and just use the ProductsController.

Comment: I'm doing it manually, I get an error say `undefined method 'movie_path'`. When add movies to routes.rb it complains about an unitialized controller

Comment: You have to use product_path(movie), not movie_path(movie)

Answer (score 33):

Add `self.inheritance_column = nil` to your model. type is reserved.

Comment: A thing of beauty

Comment: Thank you it should be the right answer !

Answer (score 32):

If you don't intend to create a model for your value for 'type', then what is likely happening is 'type' is a reserved word in ActiveRecord.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Naming

"`type` - This is only used when you have single table inheritance and must contain a class name"

Comment: I was bitten by this exact same problem. The following json fragment : {
                        content = "some content";
                        type = image;
                    };

gave the error :

> Invalid single-table inheritance type: image is not a subclass of Foo::Bar

Comment: Yep, don't name your column :type unless you're going polymorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to name the column differently (`product_type` would be fine here), and add an attribute alias `alias_attribute :type, :product_type` in your model definition.

That way you can use `@product.type` safely, because Rails will substitute `product_type` when you read from or write to the `type` attribute.

Tested with Rails 4.1.2.